# WPF Command with Click Event Handler

Tags: wpf, command

When I use the `Command` in a `Button`control the event handler which joined with `Click` event will never raised,

How can I use the `Command` and handle the `Click` event handler?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could attach the ICommand to another property and execute it from the Click handler.

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Tag="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Stop}" Click="MyButton_Click" />
```

and in the handler:

```
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
        var command = button.Tag as ICommand;
        if (command != null)
            command.Execute(button.CommandParameter);
    }
}
```

You'd also need to do some extra work if you wanted to keep the Command disabling behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [EventToCommand behaviour in MVVMLight](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

A command is a kind of week event. The good thinks about commands is that you do not need to use events. Actually you do not need to use code behind at all and events if you use a Viewmodel pattern. See relay commands: http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/26/using-relaycommands-in-silverlight-and-wpf.aspx

Comment: That's not right, you need to use code behind if you want you view to update things like SeletedItem in the ViewModel or handle in a specific way how selections work.